# Switch DetailsTemplate in ListDetailsView between view and edit mode

Tags: c#, windows-community-toolkit, winui-3

I do have a `ListDetailsView` showing some data (lets say `Company` as a simple example here). Normally the details of a `Company` are shown as *readonly*. However, via the `ListDetailsView.DetailsCommandBar` it is possible to edit a `Company` (and also add a new `Company`). A clear separation between *view* and *edit* mode seems to be a good choice for the UI. I'm using a `UserControl` to show details of a `Company`.

So here are my questions:

1. Where should the differentiation between *view*- and *edit*-mode happen? I thought it is a good idea to have a `CompanyDetailsControl` and a `CompanyDetailsEditControl` and select between the two (both using the same `CompanyDetailsViewModel`). There are other solutions as well, for example, the `CompanyDetailsControl` could handle the *edit*- and *view*-mode internally.
2. Assuming that it is a good idea to switch between two `UserControl`, how can that be realized with the `ListDetailsView.DetailsTemplate`? I though it would be easy to use a `DataTemplateSelector` here, but that is only available for the `ItemTemplate`.

Not sure what code to provide to clarify my questions. So in case you need any code to better understand my question please leave a comment.

Comment: Q1: There are several ways how to handle this and it is clearly on the intetion of developer/author to decide "how to do that"/"how it should look". E.g. You can have `bool` property in single viewmodel an switch it around on edit, bind all controls (or parent `groupBox`) to `IsReadOnly` and let it do the work. It depends what suits you the best ~ mentioned approach of exchanging view could work. :) Per me Q1 is too broad for this site.

Comment: @Tatranskymedved I agree to some extend. 1. I thought that this is such a basic scenario that there is a default way of handling this and I simply couldn't find it. 2. documentation / examples for winui3 are few. So how to solve it with that technology? Again some best practice would be highly appreciated

Comment: Jan, I put "my opinion" into answer, hope it will help you decide. I think it might be worth putting this question to https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/ , where people are discussing "architecture of the code" and "how to get different parts together" over "small-ish programming topics" (SO).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: I have never worked with UWP app, only applying MVVM pattern from WPF.

---

Straight line where the split should happen is not drawn. It often depends on the developer himself, which framework is used and more.

Me personally would go in way where `UI handles UIs' things` and `ViewModel handles data only`. That means the view is responsible for showing you the controls you are expecting to see/control the application. And when the view learns that `property was changed`, it should update how it looks.

Since the point we know the app will have `edit` & `readonly` modes, we should prepare all necessary UI components (`UserControls`, `Pages`, ...) to handle both those states. They would be binded to `ViewModel` that have base in `BaseViewModel` that already have this edit variable inside. So that each UI component know it can work with that.

Base view model:

```cs
abstract class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string mIsInEditMode;
    public string IsInEditMode
    {
        get { return mIsInEditMode; }
        set
        {
            if(mIsInEditMode == value) return;

            mIsInEditMode = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(IsInEditMode));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

All "normal" ViewModels inherit from it:

```cs
class CompanyViewModel : BaseViewModel
{ /* props and logic of company */ }
```

UI component (`UserControl`) would have either trigger (`<Style.Triggers/>`) or binded properties `Visibility` and `IsEnabled` to the `BaseViewModel`. Those bindings would handle this logic of showing/hiding and you have potential to control whole layouts, hide controls etc.

```xml
<UserControl d:DataContext="{x:Bind local:CompanyViewModel}">
  <UserControl.Resources>
      <local:BoolInverterConverter x:Key="BoolInvert"/>
  </UserControl.Resources>

  <Grid>

     <Grid IsVisible="{Binding IsInEditMode}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsInEditMode}">
       <!-- Controls for edit mode -->
     </Grid>

     <Grid IsVisible="{Binding IsInEditMode, Converter={StaticResource BoolInvert}}"
           IsEnabled="{Binding IsInEditMode, Converter={StaticResource BoolInvert}}">
       <!-- Controls for readonly mode -->
     </Grid>

  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Note: I've used property `IsVisible`, You would actually use `Visibility` with some custom converter.

Comment: That's great advice! I'll not mark your answer as accepted, because I hope to get some WinUI 3 specific answer here. As it looks like this will not happen, I'll accept your answer in a few days.